# ConfigParser where does config file is saved after running setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools, egg

I've installed my code as an `egg` in my system.

I'm saving my `.config` file using ConfigParser, but when running the code after installing it as an egg, I don't see the .config file changed in my project directory.

Where does it being saved in my system so I could manually approach it if need?

**this is my save() method**

```
def _save():
    global _config, _config_file_name
    """
    Save the config file to the file
    """
    config_file = open(_config_file_name, 'w')
    with config_file as f:
        _config.write(f)
    config_file.close()
```

Comment: Is `_config_file_name` an absolute file? When is that file being created, in the `setup.py` or when your module is used?

Comment: when my module is used.. _config_file_name is just ".config"

Comment: Where do you expect it to exist? You are giving it a relative path, so it should be created in your current working directory, is your CWD your project directory? Or should it be created in the directory your module is installed?

Comment: it should be created in the directory my module is installed